# how to generate link to next product in same category, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I want to achieve such function.

I am currently viewing exact product, like, John Deer tractor, who is under category Tractors. 
How can I generate link so that clicking on it it will send me to next tractor under Tractors category?
I am familar with some pagination like Kaminari and Will paginate, but can I do such thing without pagination gems ?

At this moment I don't have any idea to show, or what I have tried.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, let's say you have this model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products

  def previous_product(product)
    products.where("created_at < ?", product.created_at).last
  end

  def next_product(product)
    products.where("created_at > ?", product.created_at).first
  end
end
```

You could also move the scoping logic to the Product class too :)

-- EDIT --

Inside the view, something like

```
<% next_product = @category.next_product(@product) %>
<% if next_product %>
  <%= link_to next_product.title, product_url(next_product) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: .Thanks, how can I add next_product to link ?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `next_product'

Comment: Now working, It generates correct link, but when I click it, `undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass`  It could be because It can't find other products ?

Comment: Yep, see the revised answer!

Comment: Works, but It seems that It is working around only with 2 products, the first created and last created, so I need to change functions in models, but how can I do that, because if I remove first and last at the end off the lines, `undefined method `where' ` shows up.

Comment: Well, it depends on which field you want to use for ordering the products: my example uses `published_at`, you could try with `created_at` or something else..

Comment: I changed it to created_at at the begining.

Comment: Aha, I may have inverted the conditionals :) Check the updated answer!